# Access htaccess variable

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am using htaccess to block all access to our dev server with the following code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth"
AuthUserFile /var/htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Satisfy any
```

I have set a variable in Apache httpd.conf called DEV. I am using it for my config files in php but how would I use it only to use the auth when the DEV setting

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. can you paste what you mean by setting a DEV variable in httpd.conf?

Comment: I have an environmental variable that I set in httpd.conf called DEV. I want to only require authentication when that variable is set to DEV. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you paste the full output of what you have set, that might help. (this is probably going to need both the php usage, and what you have done in httpd.conf)

Comment: It's likely that there is some "more orthodox" way to achieve what you are referring to, so you might want to state your requirements as well.

Comment: What I posted there is my entire htaccess. What I am trying to achieve is to make my dev site protected so that no one can access it. The fastest way I can think of without writing a php auth system was to use the htaccess. however if I just have this code in there then my production site requires a password to.

Comment: how is the dev site separate from production? are they different subdirectories, or php files?

Comment: they are different servers. Thats why I wanted to use the variables.

Comment: use setenvif.
see [a related topic][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/329372/htaccess-auth-based-on-server-not-client-information/329381#329381

Answer (score 2):

if the request is not for the production environment then request auth. define "any" of these two rules as sufficient

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth"
AuthUserFile /var/htpasswd
allow from env=PRODUCTION
require valid-user
satisfy any
```

Comment: that did not work for me. If I create another variable based on the url it works though but is there no way to just use the variable I already have?

Comment: did you use setenvif to set your DEV variable? I assumed so. also updated my post to explain satisfy directive

Comment: I dont understand I cant just use the variable I set in httpd.conf?

Comment: well how did you set the variable? normally a user variable is made available through the lifetime of an http request using setenv apache module (within apache config, that is). so how did you set yours cuz i'm curious?

Comment: in httpd.conf I added this `SetEnv ENV dev`

Comment: When I change the variable to `allow from ENV=DEV` now it password protects but it does this for production to.

Comment: oh, I get it now. use a PROD env var instead to mark production website with "satisfy any"? so if the request doesn't come market PROD it will request auth. I updated my answer